# Does converting an object into a byte array also convert the objects it reference into bytes in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, arrays

I am currently working on a database project that is taking new concepts that I thought would be great to add to the database model, and I was wondering whether converting the table object into a byte array also converts the objects it references into a byte array? I am asking this because I am using something similar to a linkedlist system to hold all the columns and queries in one table.

I want to do this because I want to store the object as a byte array so I can save the table as a file and then load the table back up again and simply have all the columns and queries available.

Comment: How are you "converting the table object into a byte array"?

Comment: Isn't the f.ex. SQLite database and so already stored as a file? It seems odd to want to serialize a file into a file.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your object (and its members) implement `Serializable`, and then look at `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`